# Apachi nifi issues to read and save only selected column to file

Tags: apache-nifi

Let say my file is like below

```
Empname, empnumber,salary
AAA,123,5000
BBB,456,6000
CCC,789,7000
```

Now my next processor should contain only `empnumber` detals and in my `PutFile` processor I have to save only `empnumber` details

I have tried with split text, extract text and update attribute but no use

Answer (score 0):

Use `QueryRecord` before `PutFile` with a `CSVReader` (in this case you can `Infer Schema`) and `SELECT empnumber from FLOWFILE` for the value of a user-defined property (pick any name for the property you like, it will become a relationship on the property). Connect that relationship to your PutFile and only the `empnumber` field should be stored.

Comment: Thank you so much, its worked for me, i am new to apache nifi, struggling for this since two days